# Looping through a list of objects, trying to create a List view. Cannot see object properties (only _ self)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to access my list of ChatMessage objects and access their properties to create a List View. I'm having trouble accessing the properties.

My ChatMessage class looks like:

```
struct ChatMessage: Hashable, Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    let senderID: Int
    let senderDisplayName: String
    let message: String
    let date: Date
}
```

This is only allowing me to access **_ self** and not the object properties.

```
struct ChatView: View {
    var chatDataController: ChatDataController = ChatDataController()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("Background")

            List {
                ForEach(chatDataController.messages) { message in
                    Text(message.) // Cannot access ChatMessage properties here.
                }

            }
        }
    }
 }
```

[image: _ self]

I have also tried this, but this produces; **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context**:

```
List {
   ForEach(chatDataController.messages, id: \.id) { message in
         Text(message.)
   }

}
```

Comment: Would you show declaration of `ChatDataController`? And which version of Xcode do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrote your `object property`,it doesn't generate any error on build.
I also have same issue, this is editor limitation not promoting `object property`, not identifying object properties.